# how to delete total text from any table using stored procedure?

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

```
alter PROCEDURE k_exa11
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
delete F_Name,L_Name,Address,Dept1 from empexample1

END
```

Using this I am getting output
like(4 row(s) affected), but my doubt is why i am getting error with output incorrect syntax near ','  what's wrong here please help me..

Comment: If you wanna delete all records from that table then you can simply use this Delete From <tablename >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DELETE` statement is used to delete entire rows. You cannot provide column names like `F_Name` etc.
See http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms189835.aspx

Use

```
delete from empexample1
```

to delete all rows from that table.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna delete all records from that table then you can simply use this

```
Delete From 'tablename ' or Delete 'tablename'
```

No need to mentions column names that using for conditional things eg (WHERE id = 10)